# How to store results from dynamically generated forms in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, schema

I am new to MongoDB, but am looking at it to solve this problem:

**My application has a dynamic form builder that lets users create custom surveys, contact forms, etc. I want to log all of the form submissions and let the users who created the forms search through and export their submitted data.**

I come from a typical PHP/mySql background, and see some challenges in storing this data in a mySql database. Each form could have any number of fields of all types. I would either need to normalize my DB to an EAV structure to store the data, or dynamically create a new table for each form, or serialize the form data into TEXT columns (ick).

The "schema-less" (or "dynamic schema") nature of MongoDb seems like the perfect solution to my problem, but my n00b-iness leaves me unsure where to start.

1. Should the results of each custom form be stored as separate collections?
2. Should I have a "forms" collection, and embed the results as sub-documents for each form?
3. Is there another, better way?
4. Is MongoDb actually a good solution for this, or am I way off base?

To restate my problem one more time: I need to store data of variable and unknown structures in an easily searchable and sortable way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I wouldn't store results as embedded documents within the `form` document, since you may not know *a priori* how many submissions to expect. MongoDB limits each document to 16MB, but in practice you probably want to stay well below this threshold.

Since your forms are variable, but pre-determined (that is, each form may differ but the forms are defined ahead of time in some sort of admin UI), I'd recommend using two collections:

The first (call it `forms`) will store data about the makeup of each form: what fields, what types, in what order, etc. You could imagine documents in this collection would look something like this:

```
{ _id: ObjectId(...),
  name: "...",
  // other fields, for permissions, URL, etc
  fields: [
    { name: "username",
      type: "text",
      validation: { required: true, min: 1, max: null },
    },
    { name: "email",
      type: "text",
      validation: { required: true, min: 5, max: null, email: true },
    }
  ]
}
```

This lets you construct the forms dynamically (along with some server-side code) as needed for display in your application. It also gives information about what the fields are and what validation is required for them, which you can use during form submission. You'll want an index on URL or whatever field you use to determine which form to display when serving web requests.

The second collection, `submissions` or something, would store the submitted data for each form. Documents would look like:

```
{ _id: ObjectId(...),
  form: ObjectId(...), // the ObjectId of the record in "forms"
                       // that this is a submission on
  // other information here about the submitter:
  // IP address, browser, date and time, etc
  values: {
    username: "dcrosta",
    email: "dcrosta@awesomesite.com",
    //any other fields here
  }
}
```

If you need to be able to search by field-value pairs (or just values) in the submitted forms, a variation on this uses an array for the `values` field, like:

```
{ ...
  values: [
    { name: "username", value: "dcrosta" },
    { name: "email", value: "dcrosta@awesomesite.com" }
  ]
}
```

You can then create an index on the `values` field, and search like:

```
// find "dcrosta" as username
db.submissions.find({values: {$elemMatch: {name: "username", value: "dcrosta"}}})
```

Or create an index on "values.value" and search like:

```
// find "dcrosta" as value to any field
db.submissions.find({"values.value": "dcrosta"})
```

Comment: How does this design let you create forms dynamically?  It looks like you have hard coded the form fields within the form object, isn't this exactly what is not the goal ie the user should be able to construct forms whatever input types and number of inputs that they want?

Comment: @riley the point is, one could easily make a user interface for the admin by which they can modify the forms object.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Adding information about indexing was also very valuable.
How about an ObjectId to represent each custom field? This would allow editing the form field names later and not affecting the submissions.
The ID for a field would be:`forms.fields[x].id`