# Database approach to use for Dynamic Form Data Collection which is suitable for good Reports and Searching

Tags: sql, mongodb, report, data-capture, nosql

I am working on a project which involves collecting dynamic form data. These forms are user-defined (think surveymonkey) and thus a fixed schema cannot be defined for them. Data in terms of questions/answers would be retrieved for these forms and then stored into the database. Reporting/Searching on this answers (filtering and aggregation) is of utmost importance. There are two approaches which are feasible.

1. Use a SQL database and store the each field data as a separate row. Reporting/Searching is then done via SQL. My apprehension is that it would result in complicated joins for reporting.
2. Use a NoSQL database like MongoDB. This seems to be a perfect fit for storing the dynamic data since it is schema-less. However, I am not sure how good its reporting capabilities are.

It seems easier for target users to learn sql than to define map/reduce queries. How easy would it be to build a UI for reporting/searching over mongoDB.

Simple things like - list of users who gave a particular set of answers. How many such users over a period of time etc?

Thanks,
Pulkit

Comment: Unless I misunderstand your goals, your question is partly covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996949/how-to-store-results-from-dynamically-generated-forms-in-mongodb.

Comment: How easy would it be to build a UI? You didn't mention UI platform, your skills, etc. I would recommend you read more about MongoDbs map reduce features as well. It's not designed for ad hoc queries

Comment: @WiredPrairie - I am more concerned about the reporting at the moment. I could use an existing form generation tool, or hand-write some simple html generation myself as a simple UI should do. I have used CouchDB map reduce and am assuming mongodb is similar. I was wondering about mongo dbs reporting ability in addition to that, or whether it has some DSL for querying. Could you expand on what you meant my 'Its not designed for ad hoc queries'. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the aggregation framework? Have you read the docs for either? I'd consider MapReduce to be good at scenarios where users aren't waiting for the results right "now." It's more to difficult to help when your question has so few details and is asking such a broad question.

Comment: @WiredPrairie - I apologize if the question was too broad. I don't have any experience with MongoDB and haven't read the docs yet. I am just beginning to look into it and other possibilities as a solution. My understanding of map-reduce stems from CouchDB which wasn't very effective at reporting. I read on a few blogs that Mongo has been used effectively for reporting and wanted to know how it would compare to SQL in this scenario from those who have experience with both. I will look into the aggregation framework like you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already been mentioned in the comments, but I'll re-iterate that you should look at Mongo's map/reduce functionality for reporting *and* the aggregation framework.

Having done map/reduce in both Couch and Mongo I can say that they are very similar. It's definitely a barrier to entry for a developer that isn't familiar with it, but once you get a few working examples, it's not too bad.

Consider that Mongo can output a map/reduce job to a collection, which I've found to be really useful. This means you can schedule the jobs and run them periodically and output to a place that you can then report on. It's not that hard to create a framework that lets developers write simple Javascript map and reduce functions and then plug them in to be run on a schedule.

The aggregation framework is much easier to understand for a developer coming from SQL. Still a learning curve, but not as bad as map/reduce. It is much more well suited to ad-hoc reporting queries and there is nothing comparable in Couch.

You could maybe make a reporting UI that maps to the aggregation framework, but I wouldn't try to do something similar for map/reduce queries.