# How to store custom schema and entries in MongoDB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm developing an API server using Rails/Mongodb/Mongoid. It allows users to define his own schemas and have CRUD operations with instances of that schema. e.g: A user may define his 'product' model like this:

```
[{
    name: 'name', 
    type: 'string', 
    validation: {required: true, min: 3, max: 80}
 },
 {
    name: 'price', 
    type: 'float'
 }]
```

We will generate CRUD web interface for this model so users can add/delete/update his products.

There might be a lot of users and each user could define his own set of schemas and will thus have a corresponding set of entries.

The question is: ***what is the best practice to store such kind of data in MongoDB?***

I searched SF and the only related answer I could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7997624/624288) which suggested to use 2 collections: one for schema and one for entries, which should work. But as that answer is 3 years old, I'm wondering whether we have a better solution now.  e.g: Is there a better way to isolate schema/entries per user? Is there a solid library to solve this problem?

I don't want to miss any obvious thing before implementing the solution. Thanks!

Comment: No, I think separate collections for the schemas and then a collection for instances of each schema is still the way to go.

Comment: @wdberkeley I appreciate your answer. At least I'm now more confident to the approach.

Comment: @wdberkeley By the way, do you know of any libs that I can use out-of-the-box for this kind of requirements?